# Como deletar linhas no openpyxl com condições?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openpyxl

Estou tentando deletar linhas que possuem dados repetidos dessa forma:

```
nome = sheet['I2'].value
for coluna in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=9, max_col=9, min_row=3):
    for celula in coluna:
        if celula.value == nome:
            sheet.delete_rows(celula,1)
        else:
            nome = celula.value
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Cell'

Alguém sabe uma solução?

Answer (score -1):

Eu também estava com esta dúvida e verifiquei na documentação do openpyxls que o delete_rows precisa do index da linha, ou seja, o número da linha e quantas linhas você precisa deletar. Você consegue acessar o número da linha na propriedade row da cell.

```
sheet.delete_rows(celula.row,1)
```